# LINQ to Entities, SQL Server version and setting ProviderManifestToken at runtime

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-entities, versioning

We have developers some developers who are developing against a SQL Server 2005 database, while others are using 2008.

We just discovered that generating the edmx against a 2008 database set the ProviderManifestToken to 2008, which means some queries won't work against a 2005 database.

While this is a [known issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896273.aspx), is there any way to set this value at run time, based on a config file?

Comment: Just generate your models with 2005. Is it so hard to get your developers to use the correct server? It's not just the runtime SQL which the `ProviderManifestToken` changes; it's also the data types. You should generate your model against the minimum DB version you'll support.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [MSBuild.Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/), I added a BeforeBuild Target that uses the XmlUpdate task to always change the ProviderManifestToken to 2005, in case someone changed it by updating the data model.

Here is the BeforeBuild Target:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<XmlUpdate Prefix="ssdl"
            Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl"
            XPath="//ssdl:Schema/@ProviderManifestToken"
            XmlFileName="Model.edmx"
            Value="2005"/>
```